# Price and price elasticity problem in Economics

Tags: economics

I cannot figure out this problem, if anyone can just point me in the right direction that would be great.

> The price is $\$20$ and the price elasticity changes from $-2$ to $-3.$  If $\$20$ was the optimal price at $-2$, then what is it at $-3$?

If no one can help that is fine, I just thought this might be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal pricing rule for a profit maximizing monopolist is $MR = MC$ (marginal revenue = marginal cost). However, we know the following relationship between $MR$ and the elasticity $\epsilon$:
$$MR = P \left( 1- \dfrac{1}{|\epsilon|} \right)$$

Equating the two we get
$$MC = P \left( 1- \dfrac{1}{|\epsilon|} \right) \Rightarrow MC = 20(1-0.5) = 10.
$$
If the elasticity shifts, we now have
$$
P = \left(\dfrac{|\epsilon|}{|\epsilon|-1} \right)MC = \left(\dfrac{3}{3-1} \right)(10)=15.
$$